# How to send HTTP post request to another API in c#?

Tags: .net, http, request

I want to send a http request that containing string value to another api. I want to save the incoming response as an entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
//Yours entity.
MyEntity myEntity;
HttpResponseMessage response;
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
     httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://yourApiAdress.com");
     //Yours string value.
     var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
     {
          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MyStringContent", "someString")
     });
     //Sending http post request.
     response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"rest/of/apiadress/", content);
 }    

 //Here you save your response to Entity:

 var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
 //Options to mach yours naming styles.
 var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
 {
       PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
       PropertyNamingPolicy = SnakeCaseNamingPolicy.Instance
 };
 //Here you go. Yours response as an entity:
 myEntity = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<MyEntity>(contentStream, options);
```

Snake case naming policy:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization; //For SnakeCaseNamingPolicy.

public class SnakeCaseNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
    private readonly SnakeCaseNamingStrategy _newtonsoftSnakeCaseNamingStrategy
        = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy();

    public static SnakeCaseNamingPolicy Instance { get; } = new SnakeCaseNamingPolicy();

    public override string ConvertName(string name)
    {
        return _newtonsoftSnakeCaseNamingStrategy.GetPropertyName(name, false);
    }
}
```

If yours another API JSON response looks like:

```
{
  "some_object" : "someValue",
}
```

Then your entity should look like:

```
public class MyEntity
{
     public object SomeObject { get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This shows you how to send a HttpPost request in .NET. https://zetcode.com/csharp/httpclient/